# node can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

i know this question asked many time before but still i'm struggling to figure this out. i have a set of js files. first one is `index.js`

```
app.all('/backend/*/*', function(req, res){ // backend/product/getProduct 
    serviceType = req.params[0]; 
    methodType  = req.params[1];  

    exports.serviceType= serviceType;  
    exports.methodType= methodType;   

    main.checkService()
});
```

in here im extracting the params and call `checkService` method in `main.js` file

**main.js**

```
function checkService(){

    switch(index.serviceType){
        case  'product': 
            product.checkMethod();
            break;

        default :
            console.log('no such service')
    }
}
```

then it move to `product.js` file

```
function checkMethod(){ 

    var methodName = index.methodType,
        res = index.res,
        req = index.req;

    switch(methodName){ 
        case 'samplePost':
            var body = req.body; 
            proHan.samplePost(body,function(data,msg,status){
                sendRes(data,msg,status);
            });
            break;

        default :
            console.log('no such method')
    }

    function sendRes(jsonObj,msg,status){
        var resObj = {
            status : status,
            result : jsonObj,
            message : msg
        }
        res.json(resObj);
    }
```

first it moves to `samplePost` method in `handler.js`
once the http req finised executing, callback return the results and call `sendRes` method and send the json

```
function samplePost(jsonString,cb){ 
    var res = config.setClient('nodeSample');
    // jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    res.byKeyField('name').sendPost(jsonString,function(data,msg,status){
        cb(data,msg,status); 
    });
}
```

to send http req i written a common file. that is `config.js`

```
function setClient(_cls){ 
  var client = new Client(url);
  return client;
}

function parentClient(url){  
    this.postBody = {
      "Object":{}, 
      "Parameters":{
        "KeyProperty":""
      }
    };


}

function paramChild(){
    parentClient.apply( this, arguments );   

    this.byKeyField = function(_key){
      this.postBody.Parameters.KeyProperty = _key;
      return this;
    } 
}  

function Client(url){
    parentClient.apply( this, arguments ); 

    this.sendPost = function(_body,cb){
      _body = (_body) || {};

      this.postBody.Object = _body;

      var options = {  
          host : 'www.sample.com',
          port : 3300,
          path:  '/somrthing',
          headers: { 
              'securityToken' : '123'
          }
      };

      options.method = "POST";  

      var req = http.request(options, function(response){
        var str = ''
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
          str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
          cb(JSON.parse('[]'),'success',200)  
        });

      });
      //This is the data we are posting, it needs to be a string or a buffer
      req.on('error', function(response) { 
        cb(JSON.parse('[]'),response.errno,response.code)
      }); 

      req.write(JSON.stringify(this.postBody));
      req.end();
    }
}


paramChild.prototype = new parentClient();  
Client.prototype = new paramChild();
```

when i send the first req its work but from then again the server crashes. it seems like i can't call `res.end` method again in a callback method. how can i fix this. thank you.

Comment: Do you have a git link? to try it out

Comment: @Shankar Shastri  unfortunately no

Comment: Because of how http works, you cannot send multiple responses to one requests... You have two options, either merge two responses to send at once or use socket in place of http,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't call res.end two times. Here is a simple exemple to deal with callback with a basic node server.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 4242;
let something = true;

function callback(req, res) {
    something = !something;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Callback Hello World\n');
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  if (something) {
    callback(req, res);
  } else {
    something = !something;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World\n');
  }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```